# React application with side menu and display components based on the selected menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to developing in React and Javascript. I am bulding an application with a side menu. I wanted to display different components based on the selection in side menu. Can someone guide me how to do this. I am attaching my menu component and index code here.

```
 class AppIndex extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
         }

   render () {
     return (
        <Navbar />

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <MenuComponent/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    // I need to add the components here based on selected item in menu
                 </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
  }

class MenuComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
      <ul className=" nav nav-pills mr-auto flex-column">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Overview
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Component1
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Component2
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Component3
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Component4
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                 Component5
                            </li>
                          </ul>

             );
        }
   }
```

Comment: using react-router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

im sorry i didnt see your top level component.

Now from my experience, i wanna give you a little advice, don't let any child component render  another component. try to avoid that as much as possible.

Here's what i would do.

This is the Top Level Component

```
 class AppIndex extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = { component: '' };
this.selectComponent = this.selectComponent.bind(this); // dont forget to bind

             }

selectComponent(event){ // this will take the name of the button thats beeing clicked and sets name of button to state
event.preventDefault();

this.setState({component: event.target.name});
}



 render () {
   let toRender = null;

   switch(this.state.component)
    {
      case "component 1":
      toRender = <Component1/>

      case "component 2":
      toRender = <Component2/>

      case "component 3":
      toRender = <Component3/>

    }

     return (
        <Navbar />

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <MenuComponent onClick = {this.selectComponent}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    {toRender} //here goes the component
                 </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
  }
```

this is the menu

```
const MenuComponent = ({onClick}) => { // you dont need a class component for this
return (

    <ul className=" nav nav-pills mr-auto flex-column">
        <li className="nav-item">Overview</li>

         <li className="nav-item"> <button onClick = {onClick} name = "component 1">Component1</button></li>
         <li className="nav-item"> <button onClick = {onClick} name = "component 2">Component2</button></li>
         <li className="nav-item"> <button onClick = {onClick} name = "component 3">Component3</button></li>

    </ul>

         );
```

}

thats it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. What if I need to change the property of button being clicked. (to show the active component in menubar)

Answer (score 0):

easy.. You already have the name of the button in the top level component's state right?
send it down as props to the MenuComponent and on every button write something like,

here im assuming the name of the props the MenuComponent get is name

```
<li className="nav-item"> <button className = {this.props.name === "component 1"?"Active":""} onClick = {onClick} name = "component 1">Component1</button></li>
```